# Since InputStream.read(byte[] b) is a buffered read method, does it share the efficiency of a BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, io

Since InputStream.read(byte[] b) is a buffered read method, does it share the efficiency of a BufferedInputStream without having additional functionality?

I have read through the documentation and cannot seem to find relevant topics on stackoverflow or other sources.

Comment: Which method are you talking about exactly?

Comment: For `InputStream#read(byte[])` that will attempt to read at least one byte. If that is "efficient" or not depends on what kind of stream this is. It could block for a long time. And the next `read` call can also block again. The stream does not have to buffer anything.

Comment: It reads into a buffer, but it isn't a 'buffered read' method in the sense that `BufferedInputStream` is buffered. The latter can read ahead.

Comment: Thanks @user207421 that's what I was looking for!